# Convert a string array into a double array

Tags: java, arrays

I know there are many questions to this problem on here but I did all those solutions and it still doesn't work. For some reason it only stores the first input

My Input:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Expected Output:

```
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
```

Actual Output:

```
[1.0]
```

Code

```
inputValue = stdin.readLine (); //Reads input
    String [] input = inputValue.split ("\\R"); 
    double [] numbers = new double[input.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(input[i]);}
```

Comment: why r u reading it as a string you can simply read values as a `double` and put it in the array directly. there is no need of extra `String` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The input file contains 4 separate lines.

`readline()` reads only a single line

You only read and processed one line.  This will process all the input into an `ArrayList`, which you can later convert to an array if you really need to.

```
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
while( (inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
    numbers.add(Double.valueOf(inputValue);
}
```

Comment: Well I have it running through a while loop, I just thought my error was coming from those lines of code

Comment: You should step through both versions in your IDE debugger to see how they differ.

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` will read *line*, not the whole input.

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String inputValue;
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // read the input
        ArrayList<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>(); // Requires JRE >= 1.5
        while((inputValue = stdin.readLine ()) != null) //Reads input
            inputList.add(inputValue);

        // convert what is read to double
        double [] numbers = new double[inputList.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(inputList.get(i));
        }

        // print what is read
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i =0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            if (i > 0) System.out.print(",");
            System.out.print(numbers[i]);   
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is **Java 8** smart code.

```
String [] input = ... 
double [] numbers= Arrays.stream(input).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).toArray();
```